# Changing iframe src if page doesn't load

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events, src

I've been using the code below to change an image src if the path is invalid. I'd like to do the same thing with iFrame srcs but can't get it to work. Any help appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This example assigns an "onerror" event to an img element with an 
incorrect src path, then changes the path to a default one that works.</p>

<img name="image" onerror="changeUrl()" src="http://www.xyziiijj.jpg">


<script>

function changeUrl() {
var site = "http://www.cw-testing.co.uk/SportsTickets-
testing/images/marker.png";
document.getElementsByName('image')[0].src = site;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might need to concatenate the two lines in your site variable. Also, is there any reason why you're not accessing the <img> by ID?

Comment: In the end I'm hoping to use an iframe instead of an image and it already has an iframe name.